# Why are my site certificates different on different machines?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate

I have 2 AWS CentOS machines behind a load balancer. They are both spun up from the same AMI image and they both have the same contents in the `/etc/pki` directories. They have the same Apache config files yet when I run this command

`openssl s_client -connect app.eventstag.com:443 -showcerts < /dev/null`

on one server I get this response saying the `certificate has expired`

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-229 ~]$ openssl s_client -connect app.eventstag.com:443 -showcerts < /dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = --, ST = SomeState, L = SomeCity, O = SomeOrganization, OU = SomeOrganizationalUnit, CN = ip-10-35-175-109, emailAddress = root@ip-10-35-175-109
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = --, ST = SomeState, L = SomeCity, O = SomeOrganization, OU = SomeOrganizationalUnit, CN = ip-10-35-175-109, emailAddress = root@ip-10-35-175-109
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Oct  2 15:00:28 2014 GMT
verify return:1
depth=0 C = --, ST = SomeState, L = SomeCity, O = SomeOrganization, OU = SomeOrganizationalUnit, CN = ip-10-35-175-109, emailAddress = root@ip-10-35-175-109
notAfter=Oct  2 15:00:28 2014 GMT
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=--/ST=SomeState/L=SomeCity/O=SomeOrganization/OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit/CN=ip-10-35-175-109/emailAddress=root@ip-10-35-175-109
   i:/C=--/ST=SomeState/L=SomeCity/O=SomeOrganization/OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit/CN=ip-10-35-175-109/emailAddress=root@ip-10-35-175-109
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDKzCCAp ... etc ... FnTU0pdDnlA9o9U=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=--/ST=SomeState/L=SomeCity/O=SomeOrganization/OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit/CN=ip-10-35-175-109/emailAddress=root@ip-10-35-175-109
issuer=/C=--/ST=SomeState/L=SomeCity/O=SomeOrganization/OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit/CN=ip-10-35-175-109/emailAddress=root@ip-10-35-175-109
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1378 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 4E... etc ... 9FC
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: B463... etc ... EE28
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 64 d6 ae 1a e2 bb d4 98-67 c0 96 a9 7b 00 85 a7   d.......g...{...
        ... etc ... 
    00b0 - 20 b4 ce b8 2e b3 a3 60-87 c1 f2 52 3d 8a ee 9b    ......`...R=...

    Start Time: 1523527409
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
---
DONE
```

And on the 2nd server with exactly the same command I get this result which says the certificate is `ok`

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-213 ~]$ openssl s_client -connect app.eventstag.com:443 -showcerts < /dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.eventstag.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.eventstag.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF ... etc ... xIg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE ... etc ... 8BDAB
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE ... etc ... jDCm
rw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 3 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE ... etc ... /bvZ8=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.eventstag.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5267 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: B8 ... etc ... 1CB
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: B4 ... etc ... 5F0D
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1523535812
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

The certificate when viewed in a browser is also fine. It looks like the 1st server is trying to use a self-signed certificate created a long time ago but I don't know where or why it is using it or how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

See your `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` and the `<VirtualHost>` for `app.eventstag.com` for the SSL configuration directives. On AWS this should by default point to the `/etc/pki`:

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

However, if this has been changed, the certificate and the key may be stored somewhere else, making the contents of the `/etc/pki` irrelevant.

If you are not sure where this is configured, let the output of command `sudo apachectl -S` guide you: you can see the file and the line where the corresponding configuration begins, e.g.

```
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/path/to/file.conf:line)
         port 443 namevhost app.example.com (/etc/path/to/file.conf:line)
```

Comment: Yes I have those lines in my ssl.conf on both servers

Comment: I think the issue must be on the requesting server though, rather than on Apache, since the browser and one of the servers validates the certificate correctly

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my hosts file on one of the servers was pointing to itself, while the other server had it commented out. This meant that the server that worked was pointing to the certificate on the load balancer, while the other server was going straight to localhost where the certificate was not set up correctly.